# Convert double quote to single quote in a list

Tags: python, list

Im running the following code to create a list from an NLP job on 3 wav files. At the bottom is the output. If you look closely at the output you can see that the second file is wrapped in double quotes, but the first and third are wrapped in single quotes. I need all 3 to be wrapped in single quotes for the subsequent LDA to work. I could use your help please.

Code snippet:

```
for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    hellow=sr.AudioFile(my_bucket_object.key)
    with hellow as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
    try:
        s = r.recognize_google(audio)
        transcription.append(s) 
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: "+str(e))
```

What I've tried:

```
new_transcription = transcription.replace(“””, “’”)
        
File "<ipython-input-46-8cd8d9cafbcf>", line 2
new_transcription = transcription.replace(“””, “’”)
                                                    
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier




for i in range(len(transcription)):
if a_list[i] == "\"":
a_list[i] = "'"
print(a_list)
Made no changes to the file


for i in range(len(transcription)):
    if a_list[i] == “\””:
        a_list[i] = “’”
print(a_list)

  File "<ipython-input-36-837616193fb3>", line 3
    if a_list[i] == “\””:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Output ( transcription )
['Birch canoe slid on the smooth plank glue the sea to a dark blue background it is easy to tell the depth of a well these day the chicken leg of a variegated rice is often served in roundels the juice of lemons mix find the boxes on the side the pump truck the ha grimstead topcon and garbage for hours of Citi workspace a large-sized and stockings in the hearts of cell', "the boy was there when the sun rose arata's you to catch pink salmon the source of the huge river is the Clear Spring kick the ball fit and follow-through help the women get back to her feet the pot of tea help to pass the evening Smoky fires black flame in heat to stop cousin brought the man saw to saw Breeze came across the sea the girl at the booth so 50 bonds", 'small pup nautical in the sock the fifth twisted and turned on the bent hook precipice and sew a button on the vent swan-dive was Far short of perfect beauty of the views done the young boy to blue fish swim in the tank her purse was full of useless trash Nicole Reardon through the tall rider and inhale the same morning rebirth allowed for pleasure']

Answer (score 1):

Put a backslash in front of the quotation mark in a string

```
new_transcription = transcription.replace(“\””, “’”)
```

Otherwise python thinks your ending the string with your quotation mark and then it doesnt know what the next quotation mark is doing there so you get invalid character

Edit: The second problem is that you used the wrong quotation marks:
It looks like you have two different quotation marks.

" (U+0022 : QUOTATION MARK {double quote})  is the one that python uses, in your code snippet you used these here:

“ (U+201C : LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK {double turned comma quotation mark}) and

” (U+201D : RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK {double comma quotation mark})

That is not allowed in python

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. However, that doesn't seem to work for me:   new_transcription = transcription.replace(“\””, “’”).         File "<ipython-input-29-1937d14d2691>", line 1
    new_transcription = transcription.replace(“\””, “’”)
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: This is over my head but I do appreciate the help.. If I change from what I had been trying, to your code above, I get an error. These two version both throw errors:           new_transcription = transcription.replace("\", "'").        new_transcription = transcription.replace(“\””, “’”)

Comment: In that case could you share a bit more code, specifically where you actually put the code and where you print it?

Comment: The code is on an AWS hosted notebook. Here is the print statement:      #Look at the list
print(transcription) Im not sure if thats what you wanted.

Comment: I was hoping you could send me a script so that i can reproduce the issue